# How to use google play order status api in php

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to fetch order status in real time in php but not able to find proper way or documentation so I can go ahead.

In sales api I am getting details of sold subscription, but I want payment pending and cancelled orders too.

In Documentation I got below link
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/monetization.subscriptions/list

Gets below output when I run it in Try this method

{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "The project ID used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
}

But i am not able to  implement it in PHP.

Comment: Show your code, plz

Comment: The message is pretty clear. Have you followed the [Getting started](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started)?
The first step you are supposed to do is to link your developer account.

Comment: @code Spirit : Yes I have linked play store with google console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question so I raised a ticket and got reply that google play does not provide any API for order status, its available for kotlin and java only,